# cubes created by three.js are interfere ,parts of those cubes become transparency when rotating the camera,

Tags: three.js

I create some cubes with three.js CanvasRender. I met an issue, parts of those cubes become transparency when rotating the camera,please see the image(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pafn0.jpg). When I change the CanvasRender to WebGLRender, the issue can't be reproduced. I have to use CanvasRender.

Any ideas anyone? Any help will be much appreciated.

```
for (....){
  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: color.getHex(), shading: THREE.FlatShading, overdraw: true});
  var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(width, height, depth, 1, 1, 1);
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  cube.position = position;
  scene.add(cube);
}
```

I try to set the heightSegments value to higher, it does look well, but still not work as well as I want.
The jsfiddle link is here.  http://jsfiddle.net/qcy1121/xn7ad/

Comment: It seems as if the z-ordering was not always respected; what's the point of `overdraw: true`?

Comment: Can you produce a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: The `cube` tag (from its description) refers to the SQL "set of related measures". I don't think it belongs here.

Comment: `Try doing renderer.sortElements = false. May help a bit... But if you can use WebGLRenderer instead you shouldn't need any tweaks.` ([ref](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/961))

Comment: Thanks, Jan Dvorak, updated. renderer.sortElements = false, doesn't work well. Yes, change the CanvasRender to WebGlRender, need to do nothing tweaks. But I want it support ie9/ie10, so I have to use CanvasRender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is a limitation of `CanvasRenderer` due to the way it handles depth-sorting.

While `WebGLRenderer` sorts at the pixel level, `CanvasRenderer` sorts at the polygon level.

The best you can do is to increase the tessellation of your cubes like so:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(width, height, depth, 1, 10, 1);
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xn7ad/1/

There will be a performance hit.

three.js r.53

Comment: Yes, set the heightSegments value to higher, it does look better. But the transparent parts are just smaller ,it still has the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I add a check, "window.WebGLRenderingContext". If support WebGL, I use WebGLRender, else use CanvasRender and set heightSegments of the cube to lager. It looks no other choice.Thanks, @WestLangley

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would work.

use `side: THREE.DoubleSide` in material

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jFyFJ/2/)

Comment: two black triangles won't demonstrate much. Note back-face culling is not the issue here.

Comment: Could you please share a jsfiddle for the issue you are facing ?