# Three.js - wrong rendering output

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a problem with my simple three.js code. The code contains a few lines for the setup and displays a few cubes. But the some cubes in the background are displayed in the foreground.

Did I forgot something to do?

I hosted the code on http://goo.gl/qUZKRt (press shift to rotate the camera).

Any sort of help would be great!

Thank you

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019880/cubes-created-by-three-js-are-interfere-parts-of-those-cubes-become-transparenc/

Comment: Yes, but I tried every answer of this question with no better result. And I'm using WebGLRender and not CanvasRender.

Comment: Type "renderer" into the console window. You are using THREE.CanvasRenderer 59.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - you have 2 renderers in your code, both - `WebGL` and `Canvas`. Check it. Than, since you are using `light`s in your `scene`, setting just `color` to your `material` would not be enough. So check it as well. The rest - just a matter of playing around with your lights' values.

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/FeMq7/1/

Hope that helps, Alex

Comment: Try your fiddle with `CanvasRenderer`, and you will see the problem described in the question.

Comment: As stated by @coda > I'm using WebGLRender and not CanvasRender.
And if it's up to Canvas Renderer - change your material to Basic and there will be no problem

Comment: Thank you so much for you help! I know there are 2 renderers but my test browsers all use the WebGL renderer.