# A responsive triangular prism in three.js

Tags: three.js

I want to create a triangular prism in `three.js` where a user will be able to highlight its `vertices/edges/faces` on clicking.

The color of  triangles is flickering on mouse-move.
How can i make the triangles as stable as the rectangular planes? I achieved a stable implementation in cube and cuboid but that didn't involve any rotation of planes and triangles.
Here, I've created a separate mesh for each of the 5 objects.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019880/cubes-created-by-three-js-are-interfere-parts-of-those-cubes-become-transparenc/14027907#14027907

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if the CanvasRenderer has depth sorting but you can easily use WebGLRenderer to get rid of those artifacts.